# Parse REST API output

Tags: powershell

I am invoking a REST API with this simple set commands. But how can I parse this string output.

Code

```
$Request = Invoke-restmethod -Uri $XMLURI
$Request.InnerXml
```

Result

I need the output separated

```
<response status="success"><result>
  <member>"C180-NAT; index: 1" {
        nat-type ipv4;
        from INTERNAL;
        source 10.6.58.2;
        to EXTERNAL;
        to-interface ae1.10 ;
        destination any;
        service 0:any/any/any;
        translate-to "src: 211.8.20.14 (static-ip) (pool idx: 1)";
        terminal no;
}

"C180-RED; index: 2" {
        nat-type ipv4;
        from EXTERNAL;
        source any;
        to EXTERNAL;
        to-interface ae1.10 ;
        destination 211.8.20.14;
        service 0:any/any/any;
        translate-to "dst: 10.6.58.2";
        terminal no;
}



</member>
</result></response>
```

Desired output or close to it for each block

```
Name: 180-RED
nat-type: ipv4
from: EXTERNAL
source: any
to: EXTERNAL;
to-interface: ae1.10 ;
destination: 21.8.20.14;
service 0: any/any/any
translate-to: 10.6.58.2
terminal: no
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far to parse the ouput?

Comment: @bluuf I am no big powershell user. For other REST outputs from our fireawall I was able to use below and it worked ok with everything in columns and rows. But above it comes as string and don't know what to do here. ```$Parse0 = Select-Xml -Xml $Request -XPath "/response[@status]/result/entry" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Export-Csv -Path "d:\temp\Name.csv```